# MVC Context SaveChanges overwrites database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I've started learning how to use the Entity Framework in MVC using the project template and I have encountered a problem. In my HomeController I wrote the below method GenerateContractorCustomer which when called seems to overwrite the default ASPNetUser tables in the database with the new models I created.

```
public void GenerateContractorCustomer()
{
  using (var context = new ContractorCustomerContext())
  {
    ContractorModel contractor = new ContractorModel { ContractorID =1, ContractorName ="John"};
    context.Contractor.Add(contractor);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
 }
```

I created a DbContext:

```
public class ContractorCustomerContext : DbContext
{
public ContractorCustomerContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
public DbSet<ContractorModel> Contractor { get; set; }
public DbSet<CustomerModel> Customer { get; set; }
```

And in the IdentityModel there is the default:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) 
{
}

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
  return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
}
```

My question is what do I need to do to my code so that when I call GenerateContractorCustomer it does not delete the deafult ASPNetUser tables?

Comment: You say it "overwrites" the tables, but then you say it "deletes" the tables. Please be more precise about what is actually happening.

Comment: I note that there is nothing in the code you've posted that looks like it alters the DB schema at all. Something else is happening in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @Dai I said overwrite and delete as I'm looking at the database tables and prior to calling my method the table contains all the ASPNetUser tables but after calling it they are gone and the Contractor and Customer tables were created.

Comment: @Dai also, regarding the DB Schema, I'm not sure what I need to do as I've just been following this guide: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

Comment: @AnsonWen are these ASPNetUser tables manually created in the database or using EF migration?

Comment: @adiga They are created using EF I believe. They are the default tables I get using an untouched MVC template

Comment: Do you use [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChange](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)?

Comment: you must create custom identity models and with use mapping in `OnModelCreating` method override your config for it.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I think you nailed it, I had to change the SetInitializer, now it works perfectly. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an initializer that drops the existing database and creates a new database, if your model classes (entity classes) have been changed. So you don't have to worry about maintaining your database schema, when your model classes change. To change a DB [initialization strategy](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx), you could set the DB Initializer using Database class in Context class, as shown below:

```
public class ExampleDBContext: DbContext 
{        
  public ExampleDBContext(): base("AConnectionString") 
  {
    Database.SetInitializer<ExampleDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ExampleDBContext>());
  }
}
```

if you provide a null value you [turn off](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx) this feature. See the links provided if you want an alternative configuration approach.